# Decoding the characters received from medical device Mindray serial port

Tags: c#, c++

I tried to receive data from medical 'Mindray bs 200' device through serial port. data received is unreadable. Unable to find the kind of data encoding. Can anyone guide me the right direction. Or some sample C# code.

[image]

Comment: Please show us the code you have tried.

Comment: Contact the maintainers and see if they will send you a protocol document.

Comment: That doesn't seem that unreadable.  I bet if you contacted Mindray, they could tell you how to read it.  It's unlikely anyone here would know (and it's unlikely anyone who does know would be able to find it - there's no `Mindray` tag)

Comment: Google is probably your best friend here -- lots of docs available by searching "Mindray serial port protocol". My blind guess would be that the garbage in the front is part of a binary handshake you are ignoring.

Comment: Why is this tagged as C++?  Also at this point, does the computer language really matter?  I would think the biggest concern is to get the documentation for the file layout.  Once you have that, then it shouldn't matter what computer language you use to read the file.

Comment: I tried many decoding codes but still unable to read the data. The company document recommends using C++ and Visual basic  for interface development. I was also suprised.

Comment: It was just the databits set to 8 that made it unreadable. the device databits setting was 7 which was not found in the device.